# jQuery animate - finish animation unless it's fired again

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, animation

I am making a game like **freaking-math** using Phonegap and javascript.

I need to create similar timebar at the top. I use jQuery animate to animate the bar ... it works with the first answer only well .. then the second answer it starts but not exactly when the button is fired ..

how can I make it start just when the button fired and end too when it's fired again and end also after 3000ms if no answer were choosen ! ?

```js
(function timeBar() {
    $('.answer').on('touchstart', function(){
          $('.progress').animate({ width: '0%' }, 3000) 
          $('.progress').animate({ width: '100%' }, 0);
       });
})();
```

I have tried :

```js
(function timeBar() {
    $('.answer').on('touchstart', function(){
          $('.progress').animate({ width: '0%' }, 3000); 
       });
    $('.answer').on('touchend', function(){
          $('.progress').animate({ width: '100%' }, 0); 
       });
})();
```

But not working :( !!

Comment: Could you please upload the full code to JSfiddle or JSBin, so we can have a look. Thanks!

Comment: it's a multiple file project. it will be a bit hard for me to upload it but I can send you the project through skype @drusama2 and I will try to upload it to github

Comment: here is it https://github.com/Microsmsm/math-magic @daxro

Comment: Take a look at the [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method. I think this will help you.

Comment: @magreenberg can you explain please how can it be used here ?

Comment: @Microsmsm Here is some code to show basic stop functionality. [linky](https://jsfiddle.net/h542tLjx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, given that you reload the page for every new math-question:
http://jsfiddle.net/daxro/uLd49zmp/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bar").animate({
    width: '0%'
  }, 3000);
});
```

...and here's another solution which includes a button: http://jsfiddle.net/daxro/uLd49zmp/3/

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".answer").click(function() {
    $("#bar").stop();
    $("#bar").css("width", "100%");
    $("#bar").animate({
      width: '0%'
    }, 3000);
  });
});`